# Как правильно получить Color (Jetpack Compose) из ресурсов?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, android-jetpack-compose

Я использую ресурсы так как мне нужно поддерживать несколько `BuildVariants`. У меня есть `Color.kt` где я определил все цвета и получаю и их из `color.xml` вот так

```
val MyWhiteColor: Color = Color(R.color.my_white_color)
```

Применяю вот так

```
    Text(
        text = ...,
        style = TextStyle(
            color = MyWhiteColor
        )
    )
```

Проблема в том, что я получаю синий цвет вместо белого, но если я меняю получение цвета не из `color.xml`, то есть вот так

```
val MyWhiteColor: Color = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
```

То все работает правильно и я получаю белый цвет.

Что я пропускаю? Почему когда я обращаюсь в `color.xml` то получаю синий вместо белого?

**UPD**

```
<color name="my_white_color">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: В `color.xml` как цвет прописан?

Comment: @DrMcSheen добавил в вопрос

Comment: А что с `colorResource(R.color.my_white_color)` не так?

Comment: @vitidev colorResource я могу использовать только из `@Composalbe` функций, в моей имплементации файл `Color.kt` содержит только глобальные контанты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на сигнатуру функции [`Color()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#Color(kotlin.Int)), в качестве аргумента нужно передавать [`@ColorInt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/ColorInt), а не [`@ColorRes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/ColorRes). Это не будет работать, вы будете получать какой-то произвольный цвет:

```kotlin
Color(R.color.my_white_color)
```

Если у вас весь проект написан на Compose, то откажитесь от использования `colors.xml`, либо используйте этот файл по минимуму. Храните исходные значения цветов вашего приложения в `Color.kt`.

---

Если у вас некоторые цвета все равно остаются в `colors.xml`, то используйте темы. Вы можете создать свою [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) тему либо воспользоваться готовой [MaterialTheme](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(isDark: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = if (isDark) getDarkColors() else getLightColors(),
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Где `getDarkColors()` и `getLightColors()` это Composable-функции, в которых вы можете использовать функцию `colorResource`, чтобы достать цвет, например:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun getDarkColors() = lightColors(
    primary = colorResource(id = R.color.primaryColor),
    onPrimary = colorResource(id = R.color.onPrimaryColor),
    ...
)
```

После того, как вы примените эту тему в вашем корневом Composable, вы сможете брать цвета из темы следующим образом:

```kotlin
MaterialTheme.colors.primary
```